# mysql concatenate and increment by one

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update mysql table `MYTABLE` using two value. One is `STAR` column which should be incremented by one on each query, and the second one is `COMMENT` column which should be concatenated with existing one on each time and separated by comma.

Below is the command I used, but not working.

```
$query = "update MYTABLE set STAR=STAR+1,COMMENT= CONCAT(COMMENT, ','.$comment) where ID='$id'";
```

Comment: This is not a good database structure. You should make a new table with the comments and relate it to MyTABLE.

Comment: You are right I  have to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$query = "update MYTABLE set STAR=STAR+1,COMMENT = CONCAT(COMMENT, ',', '$comment') where ID=$id";`

`where ID='$id'`

is incorrect because $id might be a number, so, delete the "'".

Have you escaped the $comment variable ?
Otherwise you may use prepared statements with PDO :)
I hope you're using PDO...

Answer (score 1):

you should but string in '' and update your query, it has error syntax :

```
$query = "update MYTABLE set STAR=STAR+1,COMMENT= CONCAT(COMMENT, '$comment') where ID='$id'";
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it more secure, just use following code...

```
$query = "update MYTABLE 
            set `STAR` = `STAR`+1,
                `COMMENT`= CONCAT(COMMENT, '$comment') 
            where `ID`='$id'";
```

Happy Coding...